# Use XSLT Variable as Field Name

Tags: xslt, variables, field

I have an XSLT variable that I'm creating and populating with the value of an attribute at the top of the style sheet like so ...

```
    <xsl:variable name="MyAttributeValue" select="/Source/Fields/Field[@SpecialAttribute]/@MyAttributeValue" />
```

Later on in the processing, I want to use $MyAttributeValue as a **field name** just like I could with a hard-coded string.  For example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MyField"/>
```

This will correctly return the value of MyField in the XML while the XSLT is processing.  I want to use the variable I defined earlier to do this.  For example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$MyAttributeValue"/>
```

So, $MyAttributeValue contains "MyField", but I want the ***value*** of MyField in the XML to be displayed rather than the literal text "MyField" when using the variable.

How can that be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = $MyAttributeValue]" />
```

will return each child element node with a name equal to the contents of `$MyAttributeValue`.

If your variable contains a namespace-qualified name, like `"foo:MyField"`, use the `name()` function instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[name() = $MyAttributeValue]" />
```